# Drupal cache clear enables module

Tags: drupal-7

Have 3 modules

module_a.info

```
dependencies[] = module_b
```

module_b.info

```
dependencies[] = module_c
```

Need to disable `module_c` now

When doing `drush dis module_c` it will ask to disable dependents as well, which is not required

So used an `hook_update_N` to disable `module_c`

```
module_disable(['module_c'], FALSE);
```

Now when running `drush updb` does not disable this module.
Upon checking noticed that the module_disable function is disabling the module, but when cache-clear happens the module is enabled back again

or if we try the below query it works

```
db_update('system')
        ->fields(array(
        'status' => 0,
      ))
        ->condition('type', 'module')
        ->condition('name', 'module_c')
        ->execute();
```

but as soon as we execute cache clear, the `module_c` again gets enabled automatically

How can we disable `module_c` alone?

Comment: _the module_disable function is disabling the module, but when cache-clear happens the module is enabled back again_ Nothing in core does that, check what custom code you have that might be interfering. Also check your cache backend, it could be broken and causing the confusion

Comment: Remove the module folder after you updated the database, In this way you can track where you are getting error. Take backup before you do this step.